# dlna client web view ... where to start

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, upnp, dlna

i try to make asimple wep view app on mobile (using html-css-js) to organize videos nad playing them from local media server (dlna flash storage connected to local router) i designed it and it work well

the problem is i go videos urls from streaming app like vlc it look like this not the real path on storage :
http://192.168.1.1:52868/web/NON-DLNA/231.mp4
the problem is that url changed after few minutes
can i get a static url or get those videos urls from js

i try to google it but i can't know where to start or even can i do it with JS or not , some one told me that i need to make some request (get and post) to the device to get content and urls but i can't know how to do this

this is device xml decription if needed :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
<specVersion>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<device>
<dlna:X_DLNADOC xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">DMS-1.50</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
<dlna:X_DLNACAP xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0"/>
<deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1</deviceType>
<friendlyName>H188A: Media Server:</friendlyName>
<manufacturer>ZTE</manufacturer>
<manufacturerURL>http://www.zte.com.cn</manufacturerURL>
<modelDescription>ZTE MediaServer</modelDescription>
<modelName>Windows Media Connect</modelName>
<modelNumber>2.0</modelNumber>
<modelURL>http://www.zte.com.cn</modelURL>
<serialNumber>ZTE0RUYMCP10201</serialNumber>
<UPC/>
<UDN>uuid:10809696-105a-3721-e8b8-08aa8970e00c</UDN>
<presentationURL>http://192.168.1.1</presentationURL>
<serviceList>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
<SCPDURL>/web/cms.xml</SCPDURL>
<controlURL>/web/cms_control</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/web/cms_event</eventSubURL>
</service>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory</serviceId>
<SCPDURL>/web/cds.xml</SCPDURL>
<controlURL>/web/cds_control</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/web/cds_event</eventSubURL>
</service>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:microsoft.com:serviceId:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar</serviceId>
<SCPDURL>/web/msr.xml</SCPDURL>
<controlURL>/web/msr_control</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/web/msr_event</eventSubURL>
</service>
</serviceList>
</device>
</root>
```